# Why are there two possible values for the degree of the ODE $\frac{\mathrm{d}^3}{\mathrm{dx^3}}(\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{dx^2}})^{-3/2}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the order and degree of the ODE $\frac{\mathrm{d}^3}{\mathrm{dx^3}}(\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{dx^2}})^{-3/2}=0$?

I'm getting two different values of the degree of the ODE.

Simplifying gives: $-\frac 52 (y'')^{-\frac 72}(y''')^2+y'''' (y'')^{-5/2}=0$

We have two possible continuations from here.

Continuation $1$: Multiplying both sides by $(y'')^{\frac 72}$ yields: $-\frac 52 (y''')^2+\color{blue}{y''''}y''=0$. From here, the order is $4$ and the degree is $1$.

Continuation $2$: $-\frac 52 (y'')^{-\frac 72}(y''')^2+y'''' (y'')^{-5/2}=0\implies\frac {25}4(y''')^4(y'')^{-7}=(\color{blue}{y''''})^2 (y'')^{-5}$ and multiplying both sides by $(y'')^{-7}$ suggests that the ode has order 4 and the degree equal to $2$.

So which one of the apparently two possible degrees is correct? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: In continuation 1 did you mean "multiplying both sides by $(y'')^{\frac{7}{2}}$"? In any case I didn't follow all the calculations but it doesn't seem strange to me. $y'=0$ has degree $1$ and multiplying by $y'$ we get $(y')^2 = 0$ which has degree $2$.

Comment: I wonder if there was a typo where you found this (where DID you get this, anyway?), because $\frac{\mathrm{d}^3}{\mathrm{dx^3}}(\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{dx^2}})^{-2/3}=0$ is the differential equation of conic sections. See [differential equation of conics](https://mathoverflow.net/q/217719/15780).

Comment: @Snaw: I made a typo. I have edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: This question is from a problem sheet. The question is a multiple choice one. The given answer is $1$ (degree $1$). And I think that's wrong. There is no option that says the degree is $2$.  I think that degree $2$ is also not correct because to write degree of an ODE, we first write the given ODE as linear in $y^{(i)}$. But here doing that changes the original equation so I think that the degree is not defined for this ODE.

Comment: *I think that the degree is not defined for this ODE* --- I'm inclined to agree, although I'd want to look through some of my diff. eqs. books, especially the more theoretical ones, before making a more definitive assertion, but since I'm sure someone else more knowledgeable than I am about this type of issue will probably chime in soon, I won't go dig those up now. Nonetheless, clearly certain algebraic manipulations can affect the degree and order, so I would guess "undefined" or the minimum value from among all "meaningfully written" diff. eqs. that give rise to the same general solution.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I know that in scalar equations, the term “degree” is exclusive to polynomial equations (no powers outside $\mathbb{N}$ and no trig functions, logarithms, etc...  I would imagine the same thing would apply to differential equations.  I think that the equation posted by the OP isn’t classified by a degree.

Comment: @Radial Arm Saw: FYI, shortly after posting my last comment I decided that the "the minimum value from among all ..." possibility I raised is almost certainly not correct, since I'm pretty sure the notion is something we would want to apply to the (symbolic form of the) equation and not to some derived notion.